# linux conversion of caf file with iLBC codec 2 wav

Tags: linux, audio, sox

Used http://www.ilbcfreeware.org/software.html - I only get static from the files that ilbc_test.exe creates.

Does anyone have other suggestions? sox doesn't seem to be able to convert it as far as I can tell.

Comment: Better to follow a good writing skills and make some explanation of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by using the software on the url above.  Also we needed to remove the caf headers from the ilbc file.